# PHP Cookie lost after browser closes - Browser = Default Settings

Tags: php, cookies

I set the php expiration to 1 week; if leave the page and come back the cookie's still stored.  When I close the browser completely it loses the stored cookie.  The browser is not set to clear cookies after exit. (failed in chrome, firefox, safari)

> setcookie("pass", "key", time()+259200, "/", ".domain.com" );

Comment: what returns time() + 259200, maybe server is set with the wrong date? Check the response headers as well, to see what the Set-Cookie header looks like

Comment: 259200 is a number I set manually.  The server's date is right too.  The header's show that the cookie is stored correctly, it's just weird that it loses it when I exit any browser.

Comment: Please post the exact Set-Cookie header you've receiving, so we can take a closer look :)

Comment: Set-Cookie: user=testing; expires=Sat, 17-Sep-2011 14:10:55 GMT; path=/; domain=./cutout/.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps. But I do this to set a cookie. Been working for years

```php
$cookie_expire = time() + (86400 * 7);
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

if (empty($_COOKIE['entry'])){
    $entry_cookie = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    setcookie('entry', $entry_cookie , $cookie_expire , '/', $domain, false, true);
}
```